# Solving recurrence equation depending on a parameter

Tags: recursion, difference-equations

I have a recurrence relation which depends on a parameter $t$ and I am trying to solve it using RSolve. This is what I typed:

```
RSolve[{a[r] == ((r - 1)/(t^2 + 5*t + 7 + r))* a[r - 1] + (((((1/2)*(2 + 3t + t^2)) - r + 1)/ 2)*((((1/2)*(2 + 3 t + t^2)) - r + 1)*(1 + t)*(10 + t*(5 + t)) - 2*(5 + t)) - (r - 1)* t)*(1/(t^2 + 5*t + 7 + r)), a[1] == (t/8)*(t^4 + 7*t^3 + 21*t^2 + 29*t + 14)}, a[r], r]
```

What I need is the solution of the recurrence relation in the closed form as a function of $t$, but if I evaluate this command I get something horrendous. However, I **know** that the solution should be pretty neat (like a polynomial in $r$ and $t$). If I fix the value of $t$ and evaluate the command for this fixed value, I do get a neat (and of course correct) answer.

So, my guess was that Mathematica spits out an unsimplified solution if I don't fix the value of $t$ at the beginning. Is that the case? If so, is there any way to get a more simplified solution?

I am very new to Mathematica, so I hope I am making sense and not asking a stupid question :)

Comment: Try `FullSimplify` on your solution.

Comment: That works, thanks a lot!